# Sender's Logo in Gmail via PHP

Tags: php, email

Is there any way I can control the contact image when sending an email via PHP even if i'm not on the recipients contacts?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile pictures is a functionality proposed by emails client. In you case, Gmail, the user #Sports might have created a Google account with his own email address and then set up a profile picture.

[More about creating an account without gmail](https://accounts.google.com/signupwithoutgmail)